# How to add meta tags from widget in Orchard?

Tags: tags, widget, content-management-system, orchardcms, meta

I'm trying to add some meta tags from widget (/views/parts/ folder) that gets data from database outside of orchard. I need to put them to head section, and frankly I got no idea how to achieve that.

I tried:

```
using (Script.Head())
{
 <meta property="description" content="ABC">
}

SetMeta("ABC", "description");
```

But none of these work :-(

---

Edit: our document.cshtml code:

```html
@using Orchard.Mvc.Html;
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;
@{
    RegisterLink(new LinkEntry { Type = "image/x-icon", Rel = "shortcut icon", Href = Url.Content("~/modules/orchard.themes/Content/orchard.ico") });

    string title = Convert.ToString(Model.Title);
    string siteName = Convert.ToString(WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName);

    string classForPage = "static " + Html.ClassForPage();
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html lang="@WorkContext.CurrentCulture" class="@classForPage no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html lang="@WorkContext.CurrentCulture" class="@classForPage no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html lang="@WorkContext.CurrentCulture" class="@classForPage no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html lang="@WorkContext.CurrentCulture" class="@classForPage no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    @{
        Display(Model.Head);
    }

    <meta property="og:title" content="@Layout.Title - @Convert.ToString(WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName)">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="@Convert.ToString(WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName)">
    <meta property="og:url" content="@Request.Url">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">

    <script>(function(d){d.className="dyn"+d.className.substring(6,d.className.length);})(document.documentElement);</script>
</head> 
<body>
    @Display(Model.Body)
    @Display(Model.Tail)
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know how to achieve that?

Comment: I think it is important to note that both of the things that the OP tried should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IResourceManager provides the necessary methods.
For use it in view:

```
var resourceManager = WorkContext.Resolve<Orchard.UI.Resources.IResourceManager>();
resourceManager.SetMeta(new Orchard.UI.Resources.MetaEntry
{
    Name = "description",
    Content = "ABC"
});
```

But it can be also used in other places (e.g. part driver).

**Edit**
using SetMeta("description", "ABC") in view give the same results.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly it didn't render anything :( Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It shows no error neither, page simply loads as usual but there is no new meta...

Comment: Your widget are displayed on page? Can you add simple text to your view and check if it is displayed?

Comment: I try to check it and add html widget to page and it is work for me. Try to add SetMeta("unique-tag", "test") to your view or reload page in browser using ctrl+f5 or disable cache module. The problem is likely something else. I can not help you.

Comment: Can you tell me more detail about everything that you do?

Comment: I tried that already (see my original post, where I mentioned SetMeta("description", "ABC") already), but it doesn't work. Tried ctrl+f5 and restarting localhost server.

Comment: Ill try to ask my collegue who programmed it all if he doesn't know why SetMeta("description", "ABC") is not working. It is really weird though...

Comment: Did you override any templates in your theme? In particular, document.cshtml?

Comment: Hi Bertrand, I don't know what do you mean by overriding, but yes, we have own themes that are derived from ThemeMachine theme. I'll update my original post and add document.cshtml code.

Comment: Did it helped you anyhow to better understand my problem? I hope so! *fingers crossed* :)

Comment: @{Display(Model.Head);} - it does not display any output html. it's just c# code like @{intVar++;}. To display the output html need to type @Display(Model.Head) like @intVar (without brackets).

Comment: OMG, you're right, I wouldnt notice that mistake at all. Thank you gyus very much!

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code in my layout.cshtml file before header tag and it worked.

```
    @using (Script.Head())
    {
    <meta name="description" content="<your description>"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="<your keywords here>"/>
    }
```

Enjoy!!!